# reported speech with "yesterday"

Tags: tense

I've got a question related to reported speech.

How should the sentence **"I didn't meet her yesterday"** look in reported speech while reporting it next day? For example, I said in the morning "I didn't meet her yesterday." and later in the day I'm repeating it.

Should I say:

> I said I didn't meet her yesterday.

or

> I said I hadn't met her yesterday.

Comment: The first seems more appropriate to me, but there is also some ambiguity. I suggest: *This morning, I said I didn't meet her yesterday.* Otherwise, it could be interpreted as: *I said, "I didn't meet her," yesterday.*

Answer (score 1):

If you said that earlier on the **same day** you can say:

> I said I hadn't met her **yesterday**

But if you are repeating it **on a different day** you will say:

> I said I hadn't met her **the day before.**

Answer (score 0):

Speech:

- "I **didn't meet** her yesterday". This is the speech (what was said).

**Reported** Speech

- I said I  **hadn't met** her yesterday.

**Quoted** Speech

- He said "I didn't meet her yesterday".
  or
- He said: "I didn't meet her yesterday".